# List of Interfaces - Inherited Interfaces, One IList<>

Tags: c#

If I have the following interface

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Active {get; set;}
    bool Name {get; set;}
}

public interface IBar:IFoo
{
    int Number {get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to create one IList<> and be able to to access the Number property in the list items and are of type IBar (as well as IFoo Properties), and access IFoo Properties when the list Item is of Type IFoo.

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: I'm assuming the list would just be `IList<IFoo>`, which would allow you to access the `IFoo` properties of each item. Then when you iterate over the items, check if they are instances of `IBar`, cast, then access the `IBar` properties. Unless you were looking for a different type of solution?

Comment: Well I'm pretty well open to suggestions here. I have more class & interface structures, that, in a different scenario will actually have 2 or more levels of inheritance, so there could be IBar which inherits from IFo, Then IBoo, which inherits from I Bar, then say,IWoo which inherits from IBoo. I would love to have it all uniformly stored in one list.

Comment: That would all work fine, as long as all the items inherit from one common interface. I'll post an answer, and see if it helps at all.

Comment: Thank you, look forward to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `IList` is declared as:

```
IList<IFoo> foos = new List<IFoo>();
```

Simply check if a given element is of a certain type and if it is, then perform the cast and you'll have access to the properties.

e.g.

```
foreach(IFoo element in foos){
    if(element is IBar){
       IBar bar = (IBar)element;
       // access IBar properties
    }   
    // access IFoo properties
}
```

or as of `C#7` you can utilise pattern matching and change the above `if` check along with the cast to simply:

```
if (element is IBar bar) { ... }
```

Comment: With the new C# pattern matching, you can just do `if (element is IBar bar)` to do the casting inline.  This makes for a really nice, compact block, especially if you have multiple `if`` blocks.

Comment: ^ Definitely true, but the asker seems as if they may not be particularly familiar with C# inheritance yet, and I think separating out the cast into a separate line probably makes things easier to understand. Just my opinion, though.

Comment: @BradleyUffner good point, I definitely need to catch up on the latest C# features. included your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the `.OfType<>()` extension method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var list=new List<IFoo>();

    var numbers=list.OfType<IBar>().Select((bar) => bar.Number).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the items in your list implement `IFoo` (or an interface that derives from `IFoo`), you should be able to just check their type and cast to access additional properties for derivative interfaces.

```
IList<IFoo> fooList;

// assign new concrete list to `fooList` here, then add items of type `IBar`, or any other 
// objects that implement an interface that inherits from `IFoo`

foreach (IFoo item in fooList)
{
    String propertiesLog = $"Active = {item.Active} | Name = {item.Name}";

    IBar barItem = item as IBar;

    if (barItem != null)
    {
        propertiesLog += $" | Number = {barItem.Number}";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(propertiesLog);
}
```

This example iterates through each of the items in the list, and prints out their properties. If the item just implements `IFoo`, it only prints out the `IFoo` properties. If the item is `IBar`, it prints out both `IBar` and `IFoo` properties.